# React-native Scrollview not work

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview

I've the following layout, and it need scroll when data is greater of screen:

**Image:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
export default  () => (
  <Container hasNavBar={false}>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={Styles.container}>
        <View style={{
          flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
          <Text>Area 1</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{
          flex: 2, backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
          <Text>Area 2</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

    </View>
  </Container>
);
```

Following the documentation of react-native for add scroll I need create a wraper of my layout using ScrollView component, but when added scrollView component my layout broke:

**Image:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
export default  () => (
  <Container hasNavBar={false}>
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={Styles.container}>
        <View style={{
          flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
          <Text>Area 1</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{
          flex: 2, backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
          <Text>Area 2</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

    </ScrollView>
  </Container>
);
```

**Container Component**

```
<View style={flex: 1}>
        {this.props.children}
        <DropdownAlert
          closeInterval={10000}
          updateStatusBar={false}
          ref={(ref) => this.dropdown = ref}
          onClose={() => null}/>
      </View>
```

How i solve it ?

Comment: what is `Container`? are you sure it should be the top-level component?

Comment: @VojtaNovak I added the container component code, it a simple wrapper for add a global alert in all pages that will be your child it.

Comment: Look into using `flexGrow: 1` instead of `flex: 1`.  The `flex` property is a shorthand for both `flexGrow` and `flexShrink` and the latter may be throwing off your design

Comment: I tried use flexGrow but doesn't work for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After re-reading the question with better understanding of your complete code it became obvious that the quickest fix would be to define `minHeight` on Area 1 and Area 2's views. We can calculate it from window's `Dimensions`. This allows you to obtain the 33%/66% ratio with minimal content and expand either Area as needed with additional content.

Place this at the top of render():

`const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');`

Add to Area 1's style

`minHeight: height / 3`

And to Area 2's style

`minHeight: (height / 3) * 2`

Comment: Styles.container has a {flex: 1}, and when I use contentContainerStyle the layout doesn't give scroll, but yeah adjust inside the screen, and I wanna the content have scroll.

Comment: I misunderstood things originally. Check the current answer. I usually avoid using Dimensions if I can but often times it is easier to calculate raw values based on the screen/window to achieve a specific behavior. You may need to accommodate a header's height in your minHeight calculation as well.